# C# dynamically casting generic object at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

Edit: Changed the wrong term boxing to casting.

I have the following problem:

If I create a new Delegate of type Action or Func it will be casted to a type of Delegate.

```
var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, @object, methodInfo);
```

But I need for a generic class the right casted object.

Consider following example:

```
class Example<T> {
    Type GenericType() {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}

static Example<T> Create<T>(T @delegate) {
    return new Example<T>();
}

Example.Create(@delegate).GenericType();
```

This will return Delegate as type, since this was the type of the casted object (@delegate).

One solution could be to cast the delegate like so:

```
if(@delegate is Action)
    Example.Create((Action)@delegate).GenericType();
```

But since Delegate.CreateDelegate could also create Action or Func delegates, it is impossible to check all variations.

I can't change the generic class, so i must cast the delegate.

I hope i was able to explain my problem. I am not a native English speaker...

Edit: The Problem is that typeof(T) not return the "real" type of the object. But i'm afraid there is no solution.

Comment: Do you really need to work with delegates like this? Also stop using @delegate and @object. I was staring at it for a minute before I realized you are shortcuting reserved names.

Comment: This got off on a very bad start.  Only value type values are boxed, a delegate type is a reference type.  Not so sure what you're trying to do.  But you invoke delegate objects late-bound with the Delegate.DynamicInvoke() method.

Comment: I don't like the shortcuts like "delegate" or "object" in C#. It breaks the conversion that classes should be camel cased, so thats my revenge ^^
And yes, i need to work with delegates like this :(

Comment: *object* is just the same as *string* or *int*: it is NOT the name of a class. Rather, it in *alias* to a specific type (`System.Object` in this case). When I use a "generic object name" (which I only do so sparingly) I use `obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: It is not possible. :(

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `@delegate.GetType()` to get the actual type of the delegate?

Also, a side note: you are misusing the term "boxing".

Comment: I don't have access to the @delegate variable, this was a mistake in the example.

Comment: You can't cast dynamically with a type object unless you use reflection, and that's the problem.

Comment: @delegate is like (Delegate)new Action(...) so it is boxed to Delegate. Or not?

Comment: No. Delegate is base type (class), that all delegates inherit from. You are only down-casting concrete delegate type into its inheritor.

Comment: @jhllnd: No, that is not boxing. `Boxing` is putting a value type on the heap. Say, when you do `object a = 5`, that `5` is of type `int`, which is a value type, so it lives on the stack. But since you're trying to get a reference of type `object`, which is a reference type, the runtime allocates four bytes on the heap, puts that `5` in there, and then puts reference to those four bytes into variable `a`. This is called "boxing". Other type conversions are not necessarily "boxing".

Comment: @jhllnd: Ok, if you don't have access to the variable `@delegate`, then I don't understand what you're talking about at all. Could you please provide some real and concise code, and make an effort to come up with a good explanation of what you need? If you expect people here to make an effort to help you, at least repay them equally and make an effort yourself.

Comment: @jhllnd: Yep. Casting would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .net 4.0 then your above works if you cast to dynamic

```
 Example.Create((dynamic)@delegate).GenericType();
```

If you cannot, then you just have to do a little reflection and abstraction.

```
   abstract class Example{
        abstract Type GenericType();
   }  

   class Example<T>:Example {
       override Type GenericType() {
           return typeof(T);
       }
   }

   static Example Create(Delegate @delegate) {
         return (Example)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Example<>).MakeGenericType(new []{@delegate.GetType()}));
    }
```